# Ranking each row in Postgres from 1-100 when comparing in groups

Tags: postgresql

For each row in my table, I want to calculate its "expensiveness" when grouped together with other rows with same year/month and size.

Example data:

```
year,month,size,price
2017,1,300,1000
2017,1,300,1100
```

I tried a query like this:

```
select 
*,
ntile(100) over (partition by year, month, size order by price) as percentile
from mytable;
```

The problem I have is that rows with the same price can get different percentiles, especially if a certain price is very common. Is there an alternate way to rank things from 1-100 that would give results that seem more consistent?

I don't mind if I need to create multiple views/queries to achieve this, e.g. perhaps I should calculate every percentile first and then my main query finds the "nearest" percentile, etc.

Also to note: sometimes the data may be sparse per group, e.g. less than 100 rows per group. Also, prices often group together so there will be even less discrete values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I may have found the answer. The following query seems to produce results that are as I expect:

```
select 
*,
(100*cume_dist() over (partition by year, month, size order by price))::int as percentile
from mytable;
```